# How to import IOPMLib.h from IO kit?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, iokit

I am trying to wake a Mac up with the following code,

```
CFAbsoluteTime currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
CFDateRef wakeFromSleepAt = CFDateCreate(NULL, currentTime + 60);
IOReturn returnCode = IOPMSchedulePowerEvent(wakeFromSleepAt, NULL, CFSTR(kIOPMAutoWakeOrPowerOn));
```

I'm having trouble finding the right framework/header to import.

I'm using `#import <IOKit/pwr_mgt/IOPMLib.h>` but the complier still complains. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Edit

I am getting the following error message

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_IOPMSchedulePowerEvent", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What complaint is the compiler giving you? Are you linking against `IOKit.framework`? If the complaint resembles the following:

```
Undefined symbols:
"_IOPMSchedulePowerEvent", referenced from:
-[iokittestAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in iokittestAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The above means that you have failed to link against the IOKit framework.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Worth pointing out that this is a linker error, not a compiler error. The `#import` worked successfully.